# jsessionid in url glassfish

Tags: struts2, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a web app running on glassfish 3.1.1 with struts2 an spring.
After i implemented struts2 ssl plugin i had some problems related to jsessionid cookie. The problem was that if i wag going directly to https the cookie was not generated, and i have to ask for http version of the page and then struts2ssl plugin redirects me to https and everything was ok. The second problem is that i decided that after the user had logged in to regenerate the session id (in order to prevent session fixation) and the new session id was nor written to cookie. With all these i decided to use url appended jsessionid, which solved those 2 problems. As you expected there is another problem here, and this is that if i try to access the app via http://myServer:8080/MyApp , the jsessionId is appended correctly, but if the same app is accessed via a glassfish virtualhost the jsessionid isn`t appended anymore.
I suspect a issue with the vhost configuration....
Any ideea?

Thanks,

Comment: i agree with you,this seems to be a problem with glassfish and not struts2

Comment: session id/session maintenance is the responsibility of the container, struts2 is not involved.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
    <session-config>
        <tracking-mode>
            COOKIE
        </tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

into web.xml should do the trick, according to specification